# How to prevent the "Confirm Form Resubmission" dialog? while returning back to main page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages

Its razor page application.
I have  on main page where I use some fields to search some data which navigates me to different/second page. On second page I have link for return to main on that link click it perform history.go(-1) .but I am getting
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QNuKv.png)
after reload it navigate me to main page with previous selected data for search which is correct but I dont want any error or confirmation popup.without this error i want to navigate to previous page. Is there ay way to do that??

I want this dialog/page not to appear

I dont understand how can I add PRG pattern here.

Comment: If your search form uses a "GET" request, then the browser will assume it is safe to reload it. But since it is a "POST" request, and the page headers indicate that the browser can't show the cached result to the user again, the browser assumes that the user doesn't want to submit the form twice.

Answer (score 0):

PRG pattern is a method to solve `Confirm Form Resubmission` error.

When we try to submit a web form then a HTTP POST request is sent to the server. The server process the request and send response to the client with response code 2XX. When the client try to refresh/reload the web page, he/she unintentionally sends another HTTP POST request to the server with the same data as just before. This may cause undesired results, such as duplicate web purchases.

[image]

To avoid this problem many web developer use the POST/REDIRECT/GET pattern, instead of returning a web page directly, the POST returns a redirect to another web page or same depending on the requirements.

[image]

Because you don't provide your code, Here is a simple demo you can refer to.

```
//first page process the data.
public IActionResult OnPost()
{
    // Process the form submission

    // Redirect to the second page with parameters in the query string
    return RedirectToPage("SecondPage", new { searchParam1 = "value1", searchParam2 = "value2" });
}

// second page load the view.
public IActionResult OnGet(string searchParam1, string searchParam2)
{
    // Use the search parameters to fetch and display the desired data

    return Page();
}
```

Comment: its not submit action there i just want to get back to the page with half filled form i dont want to submit it before. its just redirect link with history.go(-1) to get previous filled data without any submit.

Comment: Please provide some related code for use to reproduce your project.